# Understanding the Degree Distribution of Watts-Strogatz Model

Tags: probability, notation

In the Watts-Strogatz model, the degree distribution is given as:

$P(k) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\min\left\{k-\frac{K}{2},\frac{K}{2}\right\}} C^n_{\frac{K}{2}} (1-p)^{n}p^{\frac{K}{2}-n} \frac{\left(\frac{pK}{2}\right)^{k-\frac{K}{2}-n}}{\left(k-\frac{K}{2}-n\right)!}e^{-\frac{pK}{2}} \text{ for } k \geq \frac{K}{2}$

(Eqn. 77, Albert and Barabasi, Statistical mechanics of complex networks).

I am having hard time finding out what does $C^n_{\frac{K}{2}}$ represents. I could not find definitions. Is it some standard mathematical function?

Comment: Just a guess: binomial coefficient? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation

Comment: Yes, it was indeed Binomial Coefficient. But in the paper it was very confusing. The used $C^r_n=\binom{n}{r}$ notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it is indeed an alternative style of writing the Binomial coefficient.